# underscore '_' character MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a value in database which contains a slash character . /
Eg.

`column_name` 
"ABCDEFGH XYZ IJ/KL"

SQL1

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `column_name` LIKE '%XYZ IJ/KL'
```

SQL2

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `column_name` LIKE '%XYZ IJ_KL'
```

Using SQL 1 , it failed to get the row but SQL2.
Does anyone know why the SQL 2 succeeded?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your column named "ABCDEFGH XYZ IJ/KL" or a value in that column?

Comment: indeed it does work, I've tested

Comment: `/` is a **forward** slash. `_` in a `LIKE` expression is a wildcard.

Comment: `_` is also a wildcard, just as `%`. `%` matches any character (0 or more), while `_` matches exactly one character. So it makes sense that `SQL2` works. That doesn't explain though, why SQL1 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An underscore, `_`, in a `LIKE` expression is a wildcard as *deceze* mentioned in the comments. It means any single character.

A backslash, `\`, in a `LIKE` expression is an escape character.

If you need to match an underscore specifically use `\_` and if you need to match a backslash use `\\\\`.

You do appear to have used a forward slash, `/`, in your question which does not require escaping but will not match a backslash.. if your DB value contains a forward slash; query SQL1 should return the row.

[LIKE comparison docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)